# MongoJack not finding object

Tags: java, mongodb, mongojack

While attempt to work with MongoJack it suddenly started to return null with every findOneById query. Even though the object is being created in the database and the ID returned is valid.

Code

```
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import org.mongojack.Id;
import org.mongojack.JacksonDBCollection;
import org.mongojack.WriteResult;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
        DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "test" );

        DBCollection dbCollection = db.getCollection("myobject");
        JacksonDBCollection<MyObject, String> coll = JacksonDBCollection.wrap(dbCollection, MyObject.class,
            String.class);
        MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
        WriteResult<MyObject, String> result = coll.insert(myObject);
        String id = result.getSavedId();
        MyObject savedObject = coll.findOneById(id);

        System.out.println(savedObject);

    }

}

class MyObject{
    @Id
    private String id;
}
```

The output of which is:

```
null
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Yet a record is being created with the ID in the database.

Comment: I was having the same issue, although I never had it working in the first place. Did you start seeing this behavior after a MongoJack update?

Answer (score 2):

I found that simply adding the `@ObjectId` annotation to the `id` of the class `MyObject` seems to fix the problem

```
class MyObject{
    @Id @ObjectId
    private String id;
}
```